# How to use hasmanythrout in laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm new to laravel and back pack, I'm creating an admin menu to (add, modify, delete) phones brands (iphone, samunsg..), models (iphone 5, 5S, Samsung s4 ...) and brands models references ( 16g , 32g ....) .

I managed to create models, crud controller .. for brands, and model, but now I'm stuck in references since to add a reference I should know the model and the brand . what i want is to be able when adding a reference to choose brand and then all it's related model are shown so i can add a reference for a specific model of a specific brand. How can I retrieve (in references crud) brands and when selecting bdrands all it's model are displayed so I can add reference. ( many searches led me to hasmanythrout) but I don't know how to use .

Here is my references curd controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\CrudController;

// VALIDATION: change the requests to match your own file names if you need form validation
use App\Http\Requests\Admin\marquecrudrequest as StoreRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\Admin\marquecrudrequest as UpdateRequest;

class RefTelController extends CrudController {

    /**
     *
     */
    public function setup() {
        $this->crud->setModel('App\Larapen\Models\ref_tel');
        $this->crud->setRoute("admin/ref");
        $this->crud->setEntityNameStrings('reference', 'ref_tel');


 $this->crud->addColumn([
    'name' =>'id',
    'label' =>'id',
    ]);

    $this->crud->addColumn([
            'name' => 'nom_ref',
            'label' => "nom ref",




        $this->crud->addField([
            'name' => 'nom_ref',
            'label' => "nom ref",
        ]);

        $this->crud->addField([
            'label' => "id Marque",
            'type' => 'select',
            'name' => 'model_id', // the db column for the foreign key
            'entity' => 'ref', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
            'attribute' => 'nom_marque', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
            'model' => 'App\Larapen\Models\marque_tel' // foreign key model

        ]);

    }

    public function store(StoreRequest $request)
    {
        return parent::storeCrud();
    }

    public function update(UpdateRequest $request)
    {
        return parent::updateCrud();
    }
}
```

this is my database diagrame :
[class diagrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGCB9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sugest that in this case you don't need to think about the `hasManyThrough` relation.

If you want to choose a brand, you need to first get all the brands from your data base:

```
$brands = Marque::all();
```

When you choose a brand, then you'll get its models:

```
$brand = $brands->first(); //just get the first one as an example
$models = $brand->models;
```

And finally, when you choose a model, you just have to create a new `reference`:

```
$model = $models->first(); //just get the first one as an example
ReferenceModel::create([
   'nom_reference' => '32g'
   'id_model' => $model->id,
]);
```

Obviously in the `Marque` model you'll have a relation called `models` to retrieve all the models associated with a `Marque`.

When sendind this data to the front-end, you can make use of:

```
$brands = Marque::with('models')->all();
```

That should get all the `brands` in the database and for each brand, it will eager load all its `models`.